# Oracle: Disable a constraint inside a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Sorry for annoying with a possibly stupid question, but why does this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE SESSION_LOGGING disable CONSTRAINT fk_session_log_ben_name;
```

work perfectly fine and just like expected, when executed as a normal SQL command,
but when placed in an otehrwise correct working TRIGGER (which is NOT executed for the session_logging table!), causes the trigger not to be able to compile anymore?

Hope someone can help...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It's not a proper use case for a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All DDL statements like `CREATE`/`ALTER` issue an implicit commit before and after the statement.  We are not allowed to issue `commit` or `rollback` in a trigger. So DDL can't be used in Triggers.

Per this [Oracle Community Post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2177372?start=0&tstart=0) you can do something like below to execute an `ALTER` statement within trigger but it's not at all recommended and a bad practice as well.

```
declare
 pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
 execute immediate 'alter table SESSION_LOGGING ......';
```

Comment: Oh well, I see... So there is no way at all to disable a constraint inside of a trigger?

Comment: Yes there is but you shouldn't go for it. Rather consider doing the `ALTER` from a procedure. Check edit.